# Test with locust and [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, locust

I have django (1.6) app and I want to test it with locust.
I installed `locust==0.7.5` and `pyzmq==16.0.2` and I revived a lot of fails: `[Errno 111] Connection refused'` more details below

When I run app with command: `locust --host=http://127.0.0.1`  I receive the following error:

```
ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7639d89750>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))",),)
```

**My locust file:**

```
from locust import TaskSet, HttpLocust, task


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    @task
    def home(self):
        self.client.get('/')

    @task
    def programm(self):
        self.client.get('/programm')


class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehavior
```

Any help on regarding how to resolve the error would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure your app is running on port 80?

Comment: @FernandoCezar I'm running my app on 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: But your locust is trying to connect to port 80, not 8000: `ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=80)`

Comment: @FernandoCezar I understand but how can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your server is running on port 8000 and not 80, try running the command

```
locust --host=http://127.0.0.1:8000 -f <your-locust-file.py>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your local ip address like `192.168.1.1:8080/api/`. localhost throw Connection refused.